# Measurability and integrability

Tags: measure-theory

If $f:X\to \mathbb{R}$, where $X$ is a measurable space equipped with a measure $\mu$ and $f$ is non-negative, we define

$\int_X f = \sup\{\int_X s \mid s \text{ is a non-negative simple function less than } f\}$.

But, I was thinking that this definition could be used to define an integral of $f$ even if it is not measurable. So, why do we talk only about integrals of measurable functions?

Comment: Consider the most basic case where $A$ is a non-measurable set and $f = \mathbf{1}_{A}$. Then $\int f d \mu = \mu(A)$, which is undefined as $A$ is non-measurable.

Comment: It's important to keep in mind that the integral is defined with respect to a _measure_, which you've left out in your notation.

Comment: @aduh If $f  = 1_A$, where $A$ is non-measruable, then using the definition that I wrote above, you could still talk about $\int f d\mu$, though it might not be equal to $\mu(A)$ Btw, I will add a measure $\mu$ to my question.

Comment: You **can** define the integral in this way. But it will lack some important properties like additivity.